# Yum does not show a number of packages, despite adding all repositories

Tags: centos, yum

I am facing a weird situation. I want to install the zend framework but when I search it using `yum search` I don't find any zend related package in the list. I have added Atomic, Epel and RpmForge repositories, but still unable to see even a PHP package. What could be wrong?

Comment: Are the repos listed in `yum repolist`?

Comment: yes. all of them are

Comment: What is the output of yum repolist?

Comment: Do you want to solve the problem with getting zend to install, or to get `yum search` to work?

Comment: just want to install Zend

Comment: I concur with @Mike, the output of `yum repolist -v` would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after cleanup of all repos, it worked.